# how do you use Yii store procedure with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, function, stored-procedures, yii

I need to change this function

```
    public function getScripts($page, $section){
        $data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('*')
                ->from('scripts')
                ->where("page_id='$page' and section_id='$section'")
                ->queryAll();
        return $data;
    }
```

into a store procedure in MySQL. How would I do this inside Yii for MySQL.

Comment: may be this: http://blog.havenisms.com/using-stored-procedures-in-yii

Comment: I have looked at that, to me it's a little confusing on that post, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Do not insert `$page` and `$section` directly into sql code. Your site will be vulnerable to SQL injections! Use params instead.
2. You can run a stored procedure just like you execute a normal query:

   ```
   public function getScripts($page, $section){
       return Yii::app()->db->createCommand("CALL your_stored_procedure(:page, :section)")
                         ->queryAll(array(':page' => $page, ':section' => $section));
   }
   ```

Comment: If i have two query then how should i retrieve results ?

Comment: I found solution [here](http://arunsri-india.blogspot.in/2014/04/get-multiple-result-sets-from-mysql.html)